# Density of set of positive integers

Tags: number-theory

We consider $S$ to be the set of positive integers that have the first digit 1 when written in base 10.

Given this, we wish to determine both the natural density and Dirichlet density of $S$. Namely, we want to determine the following limits:

$\limsup_{n \to\infty} \frac{S \cap [1,n]}{n}$ and $\liminf_{n \to\infty} \frac{S \cap [1,n]}{n}$, in which case if both are equal then it is the natural density, along with the limits
$\limsup_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s}}{\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z^+} n^{-s}}$ and $\liminf_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s}}{\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z^+} n^{-s}}$,  in which case if both are equal then it is the Dirichlet density.

I haven't quite been able to determine the Dirichlet density part. All I have been able to determine is that it would seem like the total number of such numbers in $S$ is geometric, as we have $1, 10,11,12,13,\dots,19,100,101,102,\dots,199$, so there are $1 + 10 + 100 + \dots$ total numbers. However this doesn't seem to really get me anywhere.

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9143/analytic-density-of-the-set-of-primes-starting-with-1) for the analytic density.  There is no natural density for this set, of course.

Comment: @lulu how can we say there is no natural density for the set? It doesn't seem clear to me

Comment: It's easy to compute the upper and lower natural densities.  "worst case" is to cut off at $10^n-1$.  "best case" is to cut off at $2\times 10^n-1$